# How do you put an array in reverse order?

Tags: java

I wrote this program in Java : Write a program that reads a list of integers and outputs those integers in reverse. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. For coding simplicity, follow each output integer by a comma, including the last one. Assume that the list will always contain fewer than 20 integers.

Ex: If the input is:

```
5 2 4 6 8 10
```

the output is:

```
10,8,6,4,2
```

As you can see, this is my expected out^ However, I got `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 8 6 4 2` as my output. What is wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] userList = new int[20];   // List of numElement integers specified by the user
        int numElements;                // Number of integers in user's list
        int i;

        numElements = scnr.nextInt();   // Input begins with number of integers that follow

        for (i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
            userList[i] = scnr.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = userList.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            System.out.print(userList[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

I tried to ask a good question and I expect an answer to my question.

Comment: You're printing all of the elements in your array, not just the `numElements` items you filled in.

Comment: You had created an array of length 20. Maybe while testing the input you did not set numElements to 20 which your array expects. All the values in the array had been initialized with zeros and thats why when you check your output you get zeros as a start upto the index with the numbers you added. I have posted a solution with full explanation on the same.

Comment: alternative, change the printing loop to: `for (i = numElements - 1; i >= 0; --i) { System.out.print(userList[i] + " ");`

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

You are getting zero maybe due to the array size declaration. You created an array with 20 as the size. But assuming you set the `numElements` to 10, that means that the input iteration will only loop 10 times thus only loading 10 positions in your array.

As you had defined an array with 20 indexes, the rest are initiated with a zero during array declaration. So assuming the iterations goes 10 times that means only 10 indexes will be updated and the other 10/20 left with their initial zeros.

You have to re-declare your array after getting a value for the `numElements` and set the `numElements` as the new array size. The code would look similar to below

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Create Scanner object
 int[] userList = new int[0]; // Create int array
 
 int numElements = scanner.nextInt(); // Get number of elements

 userList = new int[numElements]; // Re-declare array with new size
```

## Solution

The full code in your approach is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);


    int numElements; // Number of integers in user's list int i;

    System.out.println("Input length of the array");
    numElements = scnr.nextInt();   // Input begins with number of integers that follow
    int[] userList = new int[0];

    // Check size value (number of elements)
    if (numElements > 0) {
        userList = new int[numElements]; // Re-Declare array giving it a new size
    } else {
        System.out.println("This array size cannot be less than 1");
    }

    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {

        System.out.println("Input number at position " + i);
        userList[i] = scnr.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = userList.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //for (int i = userList.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        System.out.print(userList[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a list of size **numElements**,

```
int[] userList = new int[numElements];
for(i = 0;i < numElements; ++i) {
    userList[i] = scnr.nextInt(); 
}
for (i = userList.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    System.out.print(userList[i] + " "); 
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but you just need to read the number of element before creating your `userList` :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numElements;                // Number of integers in user's list
        numElements = scnr.nextInt();   // Input begins with number of integers that follow
        int[] userList = new int[numElements];   // List of numElement integers specified by the user
        int i;


        for (i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
            userList[i] = scnr.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = userList.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            System.out.print(userList[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array size is 20 and your are trying to print whole array in reverse order which includes unfilled indexes also. so try to make array size as numElements and print it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce the lines of code and use streams, the following code would work -

Accept input numbers and store them in the array of size numElements. Use "ArrayUtils" to reverse the array. Details about the reverse() can be referred  [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html).

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
int numElements;                
numElements = scnr.nextInt();   
int[] userList = new int[numElements];
        
for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) 
    userList[i] = scnr.nextInt();

ArrayUtils.reverse(userList);
Arrays.stream(userList).forEach(number -> System.out.print(number + " "));
```